# How to know the running scheduled jobs in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-scheduled

we can easily schedule jobs using @Scheduled in Spring boot application.

is there any way to know the currently running scheduled jobs using any rest endpoint ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you would need to include Spring boot actuator as one of your dependencies. Then you can used the scheduledtasks endpoint to check the scheduled tasks:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Just add the following to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The endpoint is available at /actuator/scheduledtasks

Comment: does it available in spring boot 1.5.18.RELEASE ?

Comment: It's available in 1.5.18.RELEASE.

Comment: I believe so but the actuator part of the path was introduced in 2.0, so it would be just /scheduledtasks

Comment: I am getting 404

Comment: When you start your spring boot application all the endpoints should be listed out in the console (as of 2.0 they are no longer listed). I can't remember the exact endpoint for 1.5.18 (we are now on version 2.17.RELEASE) but if you read the console output you should find it listed there.

Comment: its giving scheduled jobs, but not the ones which are currently running. how to know that ?

Comment: You would need to create your own custom endpoint to list currently running jobs. There is a link on how to do that here: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-actuator-custom-endpoint/ Another alternative would be create an api to log all running jobs to the console every 30 seconds.

Comment: Sorry that was meant to state just log all running jobs to the console. I don't think you can get the scheduled names e.g. method you are running because the Scheduled annotation contains no such information. Under the hood Spring uses ScheduledExecutorService which doesn't supply instance names either.

Comment: The `scheduledtasks` endpoint is disabled over the web by default. Enable it by adding `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, info, scheduledtasks` to your `application.properties` file.